# Angular Initialize one component from another component and service

Tags: angular, data-binding, parent-child, angular-services, angular-components

There is a structure of the app with `projects` component which contains `project` and `tasks` component which contains child component `task-detail` and also there is another module called `schedule` and shared folder with service and models of the app:

### [image: structure of the angular app]

I'm trying to initialize `task-detail` component from different places (from its parent component `tasks` and also from `ScheduleService` via button). I managed in first solution with `property binding` and `Input`

**tasks.component.html**

```
<app-task-detail *ngIf="selectedTask" [task]="selectedTask?.schedules"></app-task-detail>
```

**task-detail.component.ts**

```
export class TaskDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() task: Task;

  constructor(private scheduleService: ScheduleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelected() {
    this.scheduleService.buttonClicked.emit(this.task);
  }

}
```

but I cannot do this clicking on the button.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cascading-dropdown-zwsqh2). I'm trying to get same result (Task Detail!) clicking on button or selecting task (which works now).

Comment: you need to add ScheduleService in the module where it uses it
the event not fired because the ScheduleService is in another module

Comment: ScheduleService is already a part of the app module

Comment: part of 2 modules, you need to move it to one module only, then to import that module and that service will be available for you